# Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Let $X$, $Y$ be topological spaces. Assume that $X$ is a Hausdorff space, $D\subset X$ dense in $X$ and $f:X\to Y$ a continuous function.

If $f$ when restricted to $D$ is a homeomorphism between $D$ and $f(D)$, then prove that $f(X\smallsetminus D)\subset Y \smallsetminus f(D)$.

Answer (score 5):

We need to show that the sets $f(D)$ and $f(X\smallsetminus D)$ are disjoint.

Let $y\in f(D)\cap f(X\smallsetminus D)$, and assume that $y=f(d_1)=f(d_2)$, where $d_1\in D$ and
$d_2\in X\smallsetminus D$.

Since $X$ is Hausdorff, there exist $U_1$, $U_2\subset X$ open and disjoint with $d_1\in U_1$ and $d_2\in U_2$.

As $f\big|_D$ is a homeomorphism, there exists an open $V\subset Y$, $y\in V$, such that 
$$
\big(\,f\big|_D\big)^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(V)\cap D\subset U_1\cap D,
$$
and hence
$$
\big(\,f\big|_D\big)^{-1}(V)\cap U_2=\varnothing. \tag{1}
$$
But $f^{-1}(V)\cap U_2$ is open and non-empty, since it contains $d_2$, and as $D$ is dense, also
$$
\varnothing\ne f^{-1}(V)\cap U_2\cap D=\big(\,f\big|_D\big)^{-1}(V)\cap U_2. \tag{2}
$$ 
But $(2)$ contradicts $(1)$. Thus $f(D)$ and $f(X\smallsetminus D)$ are disjoint.